# Putting and image inside of a triangle

Tags: css, border

I hope you're having a nice day. 
My problem is that I need to put an image inside of a triangle div(To get a triangle outline for the image). This triangle div is created though, as if it was only a border of the div and with the div itself having 0 height and width.

```
#triangle{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 400px 0px 0px 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
    float: left;
    border-style: inset;}
```

and whenever I try to put the image inside of the triangle it just appears beside.

https://jsfiddle.net/5uv7m9tv/

Any tips on how to fix that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a `<div>` to give the triangle shape, instead use CSS clip-path to shape the `<img>` element:

```css
img.triangle {
  /* the polygon() function takes a comma-separated list
     of x y positions in relation to the origin 0 0 point
     (the top-left) of the element, using those points
     to form a line from one to the next (and from the last
     to the first): */
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<img class="triangle" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/2" />
```

References:

- [`clip-path` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
- [`clip-path` (W3C)](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path).